# How to properly obtain the size of a QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview

I am creating a simple widget that contains a qlistview with icons and a QSlider. The widget is created with the Qt Designer. What I am trying to do is to have my icons fit excactly the height of the QListView so that  I have a single row of icons. I am trying to read the height of the qlistview by using the functions inherited from QWidget but I keep getting a value which is constantly smaller than the real size of the QListView. Any hints about this behavior ?

I am giving parts of my code below.

The constructor of the form:

```
SliderWithButtons::SliderWithButtons(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SliderWithButtons)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);



    //ui->commandListView->setStyleSheet(" QListView { background-color: lightgray }");
    ui->commandListView->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
    ui->commandListView->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
    ui->commandListView->setWrapping(true);
    ui->commandListView->setMovement(QListView::Static);
    ui->commandListView->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
    ui->commandListView->setLayoutMode(QListView::SinglePass);

    **mIconWidth = ui->commandListView->geometry().height();
    mIconHeight = mIconWidth;**

    ui->commandListView->setGridSize(QSize(mIconWidth,mIconHeight));
    ui->commandListView->setIconSize(QSize(mIconWidth,mIconHeight));

    **iconList = new IconList(this,mIconWidth, mIconHeight);**
    iconList->addIcons();

    ui->commandListView->setModel(iconList);
}
```

the data function of my model:

```
QVariant IconList::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
        return QIcon(mIcons.value(index.row()).scaled(mIconWidth, mIconHeight,
                         Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));

    return QVariant();
}
```

The widget contains only a QListView and a QSlider in a vertical layout. The problem is that the call to ui->commandListView->geometry().height() does not give the real qlistview height, I have also trie ui->commandListView->height() or ui->commandListView->frameGeometry().height().

Comment: I did a simple test and removed the layout in my widget and observed that without a layout I am actually able to read the size of the QListView.

Comment: I have actually found a solution. In another post in your website I find that the size of the widgets in a layout is only calculated shortly before their display on the screen. So I overrided the showEvent() function and in the showEvent function I initialized the size of the icons in my QListView as well as my model. I also use a bool value to make sure that I do this only for the first showEvent(). Isn't there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found a solution. In another post in your website I find that the size of the widgets in a layout is only calculated shortly before their display on the screen. So I overrided the showEvent() function and in the showEvent function I initialized the size of the icons in my QListView as well as my model. I also use a bool value to make sure that I do this only for the first showEvent(). Isn't there a more elegant solution ?